# TinyMCE Editor as component in Gutenberg Block

Tags: tinymce, block-editor

I'm trying to set up a custom block that uses a TinyMCE as the text editable component, rather than using RichEditor.

I can't find anything that really details how to go about this and need pointing in the right direction. I can't see anything in either the wp.editor or wp.components objects that would relate to the TinyMCE, so am guessing it needs importing somehow, but struggling to find how.

As an idea, int ehe edit function react, I would hope for something like this:

```
<RichText
    tagName="h2"
    placeholder={ 'Write title here…' ) }
    value={ title }
    onChange={ onChangeTitle }
/>
<TinyMCE
    // SETTINGS GO HERE
/>
```

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't leave comments yet so leaving this question as an answer. Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm in the same boat and can't find any working solution.

Comment: What reason would you have for wanting a TinyMCE instance inside a block? TinyMCE isn't a react library, and you shouldn't be storing complex HTML fragments in block attributes, it's more likely that child blocks are the solution not TinyMCE